# PHP Date not working and not appending to image name

Tags: php

```
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
$id = #now=> format('YmdHisu');
$upload_folder = "upload";
$path = "$upload_folder/$id.jpeg";
$image = $_POST['image'];

if(file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($image)) != false){
    echo "uploaded_success";
    exit;
}
else{
    echo "upload_failed";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: the output is always "upload.jpeg" I want "currentdate_upload.jpeg"

Comment: I think you're missing some code. I don't see anywhere that your'e trying to include date in the file name.

Comment: ty for the response. I have 0 knowledge in php. I need your help to do that. ty in advance

Comment: @Difster You might want to look at the `$path` variable. There you can see that it definitly has been tried, not succefully though.

Comment: Except that the value of $id is commented out.

Comment: @Difster Ofcourse it is, as that gave him an error. Look how he tried to format that...

Comment: I saw the comment and didn't look at it further, but yeah, that's causing an error because $id isn't ended.

Comment: I am android dev helping graduating students trying to code upload image with appending prefix for date.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `$id` variable isn't terminated. You could just use `$id = round(microtime(true) * 1000);` as your id.
2. You should test to make sure that `$_POST['image']` actually contains a base_64 encoded image. `if(base64_decode($_POST['image'],ture) === false { //do something }`
3. File name then could be `$ide . "_upload.jpg"`

Comment: how can I format the  microtime() without space?

Comment: i want the output like this 1499564334_upload.jpeg

Comment: Edited to return as integer.